# Make Rails parse JSON from XDR Cross-Domain requests with content-type: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xdomainrequest

I'm building a client side application which cross-domain posts JSON, using CORS, to a Rails 3.2 application on a different server. Unfortunately, we need to support IE9, which means that we're falling back to using XDomainRequest (XDR) to send our cross-domain requests in IE.

The major limitation of XDR is that it doesn't support setting headers like 'Content-type', which means the Rails server doesn't know that it's receiving JSON, so doesn't parse it.

I got around this briefly by using `jQuery.param` to send the data as url encoded form data. However, some of the data we need to send is nested GeoJSON, which gets garbled by `jQuery.param`, so I have to send the POST body as JSON.

In config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb I've set:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) 
  wrap_parameters format: [:json, nil]
end
```

… so ActionController nests parameters inside `model_name` when the content-type is nil.

However, I still need Rails to try to `JSON.parse()` the data from requests where `"Content-type" => nil`. I could just manually do this in the controllers which need it (which isn't very clean), but I was hoping I would be able to make Rails do it for all `{content-type: nil}` requests.

I've been looking through the Rails source, and what I've found doesn't make me very hopeful. This method seems to be hard coded to check for :json, and parse if so, meaning I can't modify this from config:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb#L43

Can anyone come up with a clever solution?